# suggested actions inside waterfall step

Tags: botframework

[image: Output]

I am using Bot Framework .Net SDK v4 and direct line web chat client. I have my dialogs as waterfall steps. Is it possible to use a suggested action inside a waterfall step?   I am aware that a choice prompt will serve the purpose  but I want the buttons to disappear after user clicks any choice, hence want to use suggested actions.

What I have tried.

```
In the constructor :
AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));

In waterfall step:

  public async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var promptOptions = new PromptOptions()
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("What card would you like to see? You can click or type the card name"),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("That was not a valid choice, please select a card or number from 1 to 9."),
                Choices = GetChoices(),
                Style = ListStyle.SuggestedAction
            };

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), promptOptions);

        }

        private IList<Choice> GetChoices()
        {
            var cardOptions = new List<Choice>()
            {
                new Choice() { Value = "Card 1", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "adaptive" } },
                new Choice() { Value = "Card 2", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "animation" } },
            };
            return cardOptions;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the the prompt options you can specify you choices style :

```cs
var promptOptions = new PromptOptions {
  Prompt = (Activity) MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment()),
  Style = ListStyle.SuggestedAction 
};
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);



// Auto: Automatically select the appropriate style for the current channel.
// HeroCard: Add choices to prompt as a HeroCard with buttons.
// Inline : Add choices to prompt as an inline list.
// List : Add choices to prompt as a numbered list.
// None: Don't include any choices for prompt.
// SuggestedAction: Add choices to prompt as suggested actions.
```

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.choices.liststyle?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Choice set is working as expected, but I want to implement Suggested Actions.

Comment: `Style = ListStyle.SuggestedAction ` will do the trick, and they will disappear when you click one of them.

Comment: what will be the value of 'card' in this line ? 
Prompt = (Activity) MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment()),

Comment: @quest `HeroCard` but you send any message/ `IActivity` in the Prompt parameter

Comment: Thanks @HiDDeN for the answer, but this displays the buttons next to each other. Is it possible to have them vertically one below the other?

Comment: @quest  `Style = ListStyle.HeroCard` will do the trick

Comment: Style = ListStyle.HeroCard will surely make it vertical but it wont make the buttons disappear after clicking it like suggested actions. Is there a way to make it appear vertical and still behave as suggested actions. Any CSS trick?